# Top for each CPU output to file

Tags: shell, unix

How can I specify to the command top to display the load for each CPU from command line. I know that pressing 1 in the interactive shell will do this but I want to write the output of top to a file. For example currently I can write:

```
top -n 3 -b > system_info.txt
```

This command will write the output to a file but shows the average for all CPUs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this, but the only way that I know is to use a top configuration file.  If you hit 'W' while top is running, top will write a configuration file to your home directory.  Thereafter, top will open up in the same way that it did when you wrote the configuration file.  If you need to run this as a script or a cronjob, you would probably have to set $HOME to the path where you put the desired configuration file.

Comment: Great that worked for Unix. I tried it also on Mac OS but I couldn't find the configuration file. Do you know where the configuration file for top is located on Mac OS?

Comment: Hmm, that's a good question.  I don't know if that option is available in OSX.  When I get home I'll take a look.